# Redefine Row Name

Tags: php, mysql, select

Is it possible to redefine a rows name when I use `SELECT` in `MySQL`?

```
"SELECT posts.id AS the_post_id FROM posts"
```

So I can call it from PHP as:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT posts.id AS the_post_id FROM posts");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    // I call the ID with `the_post_id` and not `id`
    echo $row["the_post_id"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have already done it correctly. Are you having issues with that?

Edit:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT posts.id AS the_post_id FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());
```

Try it like that and it would tell you if there is any issue with the query itself. Also i would suggest you look at the newer mysqli_* functions, mysql_* functions are history.

Comment: lol, are you sure? doesn't really works for me :)) well then I will look at my code again